# Enviar correo electronico empresarial desde java

Tags: java, email

estoy creando una aplicación para reportes de ingenieria, y necesito que el reporte generado se envíe al correo que cada usuario desee desde mi aplicacion, pero buscando el codigo en internet todos los ejemplos parecen requerir un usuario y password y están diseñados para correos de GMAIL, quisiera saber si es posible enviar dicho correo sin tener que autenticar el password y correo y que sea posible para cuentas diferentes a GMAIL

Adjunto el codigo que he venido utilizando:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author asanchez
 */
public class Ventana_Reports extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Ventana_Reports() {
        initComponents();
    }

    String Linea;
    public static String Username = "";
    public static String PassWord = "";
    String Mensage = "Reporte Ingeniería GMI";
    String To = "";
    String Subject = "";

    public void SendMail() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(Username, PassWord);
                    }
                });

        try {
            To = txtCorreo.getText();
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(txtCorreo.getText()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(To));
            message.setSubject(Subject);
            message.setText(Mensage);
            Transport.send(message);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Su mensaje ha sido enviado");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error en el envío del mensaje: " +e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> quisiera saber si es posible enviar dicho correo sin tener que autenticar el password y correo

Con este código te conectas a un servidor de gmail mediante protocolo SMTP (que es el estándar para enviar e-mails) y le envías el mensaje para que se encargue de procesarlo.

Es el servidor de GMail el que requiere autenticación. En general, cualquier servidor que te permita enviar mensajes por SMTP te va a exigir usuario y contraseña; de lo contrario sería una invitación a los spammers para que usaran ese servidor.

Respuesta: Eso depende de GMail, y no te lo van a permitir. Si es imprescindible, una opción sería montarte un servidor SMTP local en tu red (no sé las complicaciones que eso puede traer).

> y que sea posible para cuentas diferentes a GMAIL

Como he comentado arriba, SMTP es un estándar muy usado. El código existente te funcionará con cualquier servidor SMTP al que tengas acceso, siempre y cuando lo configures adecuadamente (incluyendo certificados SSL).

Comment: ya veo, si es indispensable entonces, bueno, ahora tendré que modificar el codigo para permitir esa validacion de user y password, gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar este sitio web [SMTP test](https://www.smtper.net) para probar si logras llegar a enviar un correo de prueba, por lo visto en tu código, deseas acceder mediante Outlook para lo cual normalmente deberías necesitar una autenticación. Pero en el SMTP test puedes probar una conexión sin credenciales, si llega el correo de prueba, en tu código puedes usar la misma configuración que sirvió en el Tester y debería funcionar.